# Less with parametric mixins gives an empty css output

Tags: css, less

I am trying to compile this file `modal.less` and the output is an empty file:

```
@import "elements.less";

.clearfix{
  zoom: 1;
  &:before { content: ''; display: block; }
  &:after { content: ''; display: table; clear: both; }
}
.setheightwidth (@height, @width) {
    width: @width;
    height: @height;
}
#logocircle {
    .setheightwidth(@logoradius, @logoradius);
}
```

I am compiling using the lessc gem:

```
lessc modal.less > modal.css
```

Comment: Undefined `@logoradius`? (It looks like you use a version of less.rb that instead of printing a error message just silently produces an empty file for an ill-formed Less input).

Comment: I still dont have a solution - no, `@logradius` was also defined, I cut it out.

Comment: well I use lessc, and I remembered having installed it as a gem. It generates error messages for other errors, though, like for a double semicolon as it did just now.
Just this, it's silent and only the less elements header is printed.

Comment: Well, still more info on used compiler/version welcome since your snippet compiles as expected with the ["official"](https://github.com/less/less.js) Less compiler).